# css issue with chrome and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

here is my issue , top raw messed up in Chrome and IE but working fine in FF , 
demo page : http://sudanesetweeps.com/dev/index.php

here is my css

```
/*

*/


body {
    background: #282425 url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    font-size:12px;
}

#myTable { width: 100%;overflow:hidden; }
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 852px;
    padding: 25px 0;
}

/* header */
.header .logo {
    margin-bottom: 21px;
}
.header ul.nav {
    position:relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;padding:0;
    color: #fcd770;
    background: url(../images/menu.png) no-repeat top left;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 46px;
    font-size:15px;
}
    .header ul.nav li {
        float:left;
        position:relative;
        margin: 15px 0 0 20px;
    }
    .header ul.nav li a{
        color: #fcd770;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
.header .header_twitter {
    position:relative;
    height: 260px;
    background: url(../images/header_bg.png) no-repeat top left;
    color: #fff;
}
    .header .header_twitter .singin_twitter {
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 40px;
        right: 55px;
    }

/* middle */
.middle {
    position:relative;
    margin: 30px 0;
}
.middle a{
    color: #000;
}
    .middle .row_top {
        background: url(../images/table_top.png) no-repeat top left;
        overflow:hidden;
        color: #fcd770;
    }
    .middle .row {
        overflow:hidden;
        background: url(../images/table_middle.png) no-repeat top left;
        color: #000;
    }
    .middle .row_top .col1,
    .middle .row_top .col2,
    .middle .row_top .col3,
    .middle .row_top .col4,
    .middle .row_top .col5,
    .middle .row_top .col6,
    .middle .row_top .col7,
    .middle .row_top .col8{
        float:left;
        padding: 20px 0 18px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .middle .row .col1,
    .middle .row .col5,
    .middle .row .col3,
    .middle .row .col4,
    .middle .row .col6,
    .middle .row .col7,
    .middle .row .col8{
        float:left;
        padding: 20px 0 0 0;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .middle .row .col2{
        padding: 7px 0 8px 0;
        float:left;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .middle .row .col1,
    .middle .row_top .col1{
        width: 98px;
    }
    .middle .row .col2,
    .middle .row_top .col2{
        width: 102px;
    }
    .middle .row .col3,
    .middle .row_top .col3{
        width: 146px;
    }
    .middle .row .col4,
    .middle .row_top .col4{
        width: 150px;
    }
    .middle .row .col5,
    .middle .row_top .col5{
        width:76px;
    }
    .middle .row .col6,
    .middle .row_top .col6{
        width:73px;
    }
    .middle .row .col7,
    .middle .row_top .col7{
        width:118px;
    }
    .middle .row .col8,
    .middle .row_top .col8{
        width:87px;
    }
    .middle .last {
        background: url(../images/table_bottom.png) no-repeat top left;
    }




/* footer */
.footer {

}
    .footer_top {
        height: 17px;
        background: url(../images/footer_top.png) no-repeat top left;
    }
    .footer_bottom {
        height: 17px;
        background: url(../images/footer_bottom.png) no-repeat top left;
    }
    .footer_content {
        background: #2b7fc3;
        color: #fff;
        width:851px;
        font-size:12px;
        text-align:center;
    }
        .footer_content a {
            color: #fcd770 ;
            font-size: 12px;

            text-decoration:none;
        }
```

and here is  jquery table css  demo_table_jui.css

i couldnt past it here bcs its too long so here is code link

```
http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/c1qqXYpf9i
```

Comment: Why didn't you edit your last question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231850/css-issue-with-firefox to reflect your continuing problems instead of opening a new question?

Comment: In fact, it kinda looks like another earlier post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225002/css-issue-when-convert-from-div-to-table .

Comment: You really should post this on something like http://jsfiddle.net/ as it makes it hard to debug your issue if you're making changes while I'm running tools. Also, a good way to develop so this doesn't happen is to test in all browsers WHILE you're writing code, not at the end. There are a few suggestions I have, but until it's in jsFiddle, I can't give a proper answer.

Comment: @Patric I stoped changes now ,  FF fine Chrome IE buggy!

Comment: I see that you've discovered a fix for the code as it seems to look okay now, just as a heads up you may want to change your "secret" if this is meant for professional purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your live site now adding `float:left` to the rule below should fix it in Chrome and it still looks ok in Firefox.

```
.middle .row {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(../images/table_middle.png) no-repeat top left;
    color: black;
    float: left; /* add this */
}
```

I cannot test in IE. Because at the moment you have the code below posted before the doctype which throws IE into quirks mode and forces even IE9 to see your *kill ie message*:

```
<script lang='javascript'> 
    <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        window.location = "ie6dead.php";
    <![endif]-->
</script>
```

You cannot have anything before your doctype, not even a comment, or IE will be thrown into quirks mode. You need to move this conditional comment into your `<head>` section for IE to function properly.

Comment: sweet all working fine and i adjust condition its all fine now ,

Comment: @marco: Happy I could help, but you still need to move that conditional comment as it is throwing IE into quirks mode so now the layout looks broken. As I said above you cannot have anything before the doctype. Just move it into the `<head>` section.

Answer (score 0):

You don't think you could've boiled that down a bit before posting it?

Anyway, removing that `float: left` on line 80 in style.css would be a good start in fixing this.

Comment: already did this before i post here and its lead to more mess in chrome and FF , :)